# how to get the current longitude and latitude via android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, latitude-longitude

hello expert people I need help
I want to get longitude and latitude from the emulator the program is working on my phone but it is not working on emulator I need to get the longitude and latitude on emulator for testing and complete my project please help and here is my code